# ASP.NET WebAPI with Istio Service Mesh and AKS errors

Tags: istio, azure-aks

Seeing error below :

"upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure" when tried with below steps:

have created AKS cluster and deployed ASP.NET core docker container. Have installed Istio as per instructions below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/servicemesh-istio-install?pivots=client-operating-system-windows
Have deployed ASP.NET core docker container in default namespace with istio-injection enabled. Here below is the virtual service and gateway yaml files.

After all this when trying to access http://52.224.26.59/Home/View where 52.224.26.59 is external ip of istio-ingressgateway getting error as "upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure".

[image]

Comment: can you fix the formatting?

Comment: Yes added screen shot finding little difficulty to added code snippet with formating.

Comment: 1.Could you try to add [name](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19614#issuecomment-566438454) for your deployment service as mentioned [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/protocol-selection/)? 2.Could you try to check if bookinfo [example](https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/bookinfo/) works fine?

Comment: it doesn't matter about metadata name for virtual service. Only we should keep on eye over getaway service referred with correct name.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue.

It's because of an issue with an older version of .NET Core version.
Once I updated with .NET Core 3.1, I was able to deploy and access .NET Core WebAPI.

Regarding other issues, there are more challenges and road is not clear with Istio and .NET core combination.